# generate multiple menu items with lists in rumps

Tags: python, macos

I've built a [python rumps](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps) application with a few menu options. But I'm trying to figure out how to create either a menu or submenu from a list. I need to pull up a list of users and when it's clicked, it executes a command unique to that user.

So it should connect to an external source to grab a list of users, then list those users as menu items.  Clicking each will execute a different unique command or option.

This was what I was trying to do, but clearly its a no-go.

```
import rumps

# returns a list of users
listofusers = get_list_of_user_folders()

class OfficeToolApp(rumps.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OfficeToolApp, self).__init__("Tools", icon="officeimage.png")
        self.menu = listofusers

    for user in listofusers:
        @rumps.clicked(user)
        def userclick(self, _):
            change_wacom_driver.RunSync("push", user)

    @rumps.clicked("Push Settings to Jay")
    def pushjaysettings(self, _):
        change_wacom_driver.RunSync("push", "jay")

    @rumps.clicked("Push Settings to Steve")
    def pushstevesettings(self, _):
        change_wacom_driver.RunSync("push", "steve")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    OfficeToolApp().run()
```

I was actually surprised that this generated the list correctly in the menu. The buttons just don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wager there's a better way, but this is the only way I could get it to work:

```py
import rumps

# returns a list of users
listofusers = ["alice", "billy", "coryn", "dana", "ernie"]


def userclick(app, menuitem):
    rumps.alert(f"push {menuitem.title} no preferences available!")


class OfficeToolApp(rumps.App):

    for user in listofusers:
        # stack the decorators
        userclick = rumps.clicked(user)(userclick)

    def __init__(self):
        super(OfficeToolApp, self).__init__("Tools")
        self.menu = listofusers

    @rumps.clicked("Push Settings to Jay Bird")
    def pushjaysettings(self, _):
        rumps.alert("push jay no preferences available!")

    @rumps.clicked("Push Settings to Steve")
    def pushstevesettings(self, _):
        rumps.alert("push steve no preferences available!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    OfficeToolApp().run()
```

Comment: this looks like the right answer to me! works great.

Comment: question:   userclick = rumps.clicked(user)(userclick) can you explain what's happening here and why there's two sets of ( )( ) ?

Comment: @russellaugust it's the direct way of calling a decorator. It's applying the `clicked` decorator to the `userclick` function, and then it's going to apply `click` to the that decorated function until the end of the list.

The first `()` is the parameter to the `clicked` function e.g. "Push Settings to Jay Bird" in your example.

The second `()` is passing the function we wish to decorate in. e.g. `pushjaysettings` above.

The `@` syntax for decorators came about to clean up this "after the function" declaration. See [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#motivation)